# G Suite SAML App Icon

Tags: icons, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I have added multiple SAML Apps configured in G Suite using built-in options including Atlassian and Salesforce. When selecting the built-in options, I see no way to provide an icon and they do not appear to contain an appropriate icon (they all have a pencil icon). As a result, the app launcher is full of icons that you cannot tell apart. I noticed if I create a custom SAML App then I have an option to upload an icon -- though I see no way to change it after the fact.

Am I missing something or is this expected behavior? If I want custom icons do I need to create custom apps? Is there perhaps an API I can call to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the [Set up your own custom SAML app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en):

> 7. (Optional) Click Choose file next to the Upload Logo field to upload a PNG or GIF file to serve as an icon. The file size should be
>      256 pixels square.

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be the only way. The downside is that you lose the advantage of the built-in templates and need to populate all the data manually. Since they offer it for custom I was hoping they had it for built-in as well. Now I need to recreate all the SAML apps I created :-/

Comment: As a follow up, I did try this and it does work. It appears every time you wish to change the icon (assume that is rare unless it does not look good the first time you save the SAML app) you must create a new SAML app and delete the old one.